# Number of ways of choosing two subsets $P$ and $Q$ such that $P\cap Q=\emptyset$

Tags: combinatorics

> A set $A$ has $n$ elements. A subset of $P$ of $A$ is chosen (with replacement) and another subset $Q$ is chosen. Find number of ways of choosing $P$ and $Q$ such that $P\cap Q=\emptyset$

If $n(P)=0$, number of subsets $Q=^nC_0+^nC_1+\cdots +^nC_n=2^n$

If $n(P)=1$, then number of subsets $Q=^nC_0+^nC_1+\cdots +^nC_{n-1}$

Adding all the cases, number of ways is $(n+1)\cdot^nC_0+n\cdot^nC_1+\cdots ^nC_n$

But answer given is $3^n$.

(I have already seen two posts on SE regarding the same question but not this method. What is the mistake I am making?)

Comment: I will delete the post as soon as I know my mistake.

Comment: What is $n(P)$? Is it cardinality of $P$?

Comment: Number of elements of P.

Comment: You shouldn't delete your post once you know your mistake. Leave it for others to learn if they search for it.

Comment: For the case $n(P)=1$, you should have ${{n-1}\choose 0}+{{n-1}\choose 1}+\cdots + {{n-1}\choose {n-1}}$ because you are not allowed to include any elements of $P$ (of which there is $1$) when you choose elements for $Q$.

Comment: What are the symbols $+^n$ and $\cdot^n$?

Comment: @EliRose I believe the $n$'s are supposed to be next to the $C$'s, which is one way to write $n$ choose $k$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein people will flag this or downvote this.

Comment: @AdityaDev I can't imagine why; you've shown exactly what you've done and where you're struggling. Downvotes are for a failure to show effort or a duplicated question.

Comment: @AdityaDev: Is "with replacement" supposed to be here? I don't know what choosing a subset "with replacement" (as opposed to choosing one without) means -- we're not going to let it contain multiple elements, right?

Comment: @EliRose I believe "with replacement" means that all the elements of $P$ are returned to the set before choosing the set $Q$.

Comment: @kccu: But we require that $P$ and $Q$ have no elements in common, so they can't go in there anyway, right?

Comment: @EliRose This might be part of a larger problem which, for example, asks for the probability of choosing $P$ and $Q$ such that $P\cap Q=\varnothing$. If the elements of $P$ were not replaced, that probability would be $1$, when in fact the probability is $3^n/2^{2n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case $n(P)=1$, you should have $${{n−1}\choose 0}+{{n−1}\choose 1}+\cdots+{{n−1}\choose {n−1}}=2^{n-1}$$ because you are not allowed to include any elements of $P$ (of which there is $1$) when you choose elements for $Q$. So in general, when $n(P)=k$, the number of possibilities for $Q$ is $${{n-k}\choose 0}+{{n-k}\choose 1}+\cdots+{{n-k}\choose{n-k}}=2^{n-k}$$ because there are $k$ elements (the elements of $P$) that you must exclude when choosing elements for $Q$.

Now when you add all the cases, it's not clear where the numbers are coming from. How do you get the coefficients $n+1$ and $n$ and so on? You should add up over all the cases (which are disjoint) the number of possibilities for $P$ times the number of possibilities for $Q$. When $n(P)=k$, there are $n \choose k$ possibilities for what the set $P$ is. We already computed that there are $2^{n-k}$ possibilities for $Q$ given $P$. So in total there are ${n\choose k}\cdot 2^{n-k}$ possibilities for $P$ and $Q$ when $n(P)=k$. So the answer is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\cdot 2^{n-k}=3^k.$$
(You can use the binomial theorem to compute this sum.)

Comment: There are n+1 number of $^nC_0$s, n number of $^nC_1$s, n-1 number of $^nC_2$ ...and only one $^nC_n$ (which is from n(P)=1 case), if I were to continue doing my mistake :)

Comment: Oh I see now. I was confused because you summed the number of possibilities for $Q$ to get $2^n$ when $n(P)=0$, but you didn't use that number in your sum later on.

Answer (score 4):

Others have talked about your method; here's a different way of looking at it.

Given a set of size $n$, there are $2^n$ subsets. This is because we can construct a subset by, for each element $x \in A$, making an independent choice: either $x$ is in the subset, or it is not.

So there's an analogous way to see why $3^n$ is correct for this problem -- for each element of $A$, there are three options: either it's in $P$, it's in $Q$, or it's in neither.

Comment: I like that. Similar reasoning to the one stating that the set of all partial functions from $A$ into $B$, where $|A| = n$ and $|B| = k$ has cardinality $(k+1)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to think about the problem- 
Each of the elements in the set A has three options- go into set P, go into set Q or go into neither. 
It can't go into both since the intersection of P and Q is the null set.

Therefore 3^n ways of forming subsets P and Q

Answer (score 1):

Then when $n(P)=1$ you have number of subsets $Q = { n-1 \choose {0}} + { n-1 \choose  1} + \dots + {n-1 \choose n-2} + { n-1 \choose n-1}$